# Java mastar-worker communication

Tags: java, multithreading, callback, threadpool, master-slave

Here's what I need:

A Master task will create a bunch of Worker tasks.

Once each worker finishes the job, it needs to report back to the master.

As soon as the master receives a predefined number of responses, it will save these results. This is needed because inserting the results one by one will take much more time than inserting a bunch of them at once and waiting for all the results might result in an OutOfMemoryException.

I've looked into each worker calling a method on the master and synchronizing this with wait() and notify() and also using ThreadPoolExecutor and the afterExecute(..) method for getting the result from the workers, but I'm still not sure what is the best way to achieve what I need.

Edit: I should also mention that this is a java app.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) where the master waits (`queue.take()`) for a worker to place a result (`queue.put()`).